# Не могу задать индекс для создаваемого Pandas DateFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Имею следующие исходные данные:

```
# список столбцов
report_columns = ['Date', 'Result', 'Status', 'Count']
# создаём новый пустой DataFrame с использованием списка столбцов
report_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=report_columns)
# преобразуем первый столбец в datetime:
report_df[report_columns[0]] = pd.to_datetime(report_df[report_columns[0]])  # 'Date'
# остальные:
report_df[report_columns[1]] = report_df[report_columns[1]].astype(str)  # 'Result'
report_df[report_columns[2]] = report_df[report_columns[2]].astype(str)  # 'Status'
report_df[report_columns[3]] = report_df[report_columns[3]].astype(float)  # 'Count'

report_df = report_df.reset_index(drop=True)

def BuildReportItem(t_date, t_result, t_status, t_count):
    return {"Date": t_date, "Result": t_result, "Status": t_status, "Count": t_count}

for index, row in data_sience_csv.iterrows():
    .....
    check_signals = []
    .....
    if ...
        signal = BuildReportItem(row[0], s_compact, s_stat, iPointData)
        check_signals.append(signal)
    ....

    if check_signals != []:
        report_df = report_df.append(check_signals)
        print(report_df)

report_df.to_csv(csv_path2reports, sep=';')
```

В результате я получаю примерно следующее:

```
                 Date  Result  Status  Count
0 2020-03-12 13:00:00   Found    Warr    0.0
0 2020-06-03 11:00:00   Found      Ok   73.0
```

Как видно из вывода "индекс" почему-то всегда равен '0'!
Хотя я понимаю, что скорее всего это даже и не индекс. Отсюда два вопроса

1. Как указать индекс? Чтобы в первом столбце (который без имени) шли 0, 1, 2, 3 ... Т.е у DataFrame был числовой индекс, начинающийся с нуля.
2. Можно ли в качестве индекса указать столбец 'Date'?
   Я это пробовал (через report_df.set_index), но результат увы такой же...

---

PS1:
На самом деле удивлён, что большинство сосредоточилось не на заданных мною вопросах, а на том как я заполняю DataFrame и откуда я получаю значения `s_compact, s_stat, iPointData`.. Хотя какая связь между этими вопросами и созданием пустого DataFrame, у которого почему-то не формируется index я так и не понял.. Ну да ладно, постараюсь ответить

1. на тему iterrows - для меня скорость не критична, но если есть более скоростные решения буду признателен за рассказ о них (или за ссылку на пример кода).
2. на тему `s_compact, s_stat, iPointData` - я даже не знаю что ответить.. Там кода обработки данных примерно на 400 строк (не считая вспомогательных функций) - его весь что-ли нужно приводить? Есть три функции, каждая из которых вызывает ещё несколько, которые обрабатывают фрейм из исходных данных (результаты работы двух медицинских приборов, выгруженные в CSV). Первая - если заданный критерий сработал, то возвращает строку, которая может иметь значения "Found" или "May be". Вторая возвращает строку, которая может иметь значения "Success", "Warr", "Info" и "Err". Третья - число, рассчитанное по определённому алгоритму. Чем это вам поможет - не знаю.

По-пробую ещё раз кратко описать задачу:

1. Нужно создать пустой DateFrame, который в процессе выполнения алгоритма наполняется данными (подготовленными строками).
2. Как установить индекс для пустого DateFrame? Я использовал `report_df = report_df.set_index('Date')` но такой вариант не срабатывает.. И можно ли сделать нумерацию не по дате, а просто - с нуля и до конца.

---

PS2: вопрос решился, спасибо [@MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1168709/217579) за подсказку!

Необходимо было после `report_df = report_df.append(check_signals)` добавить следующий код:

```py
if (len(report_df) > 0):
    report_df = report_df.reset_index(drop=True)
    print(report_df)`
```

Тогда индекс в DataFrame отображается в виде целых чисел от 0 до N-1!
Ещё раз спасибо! Не думал, что каждый раз, при добавлении строки, придётся `reset_index` делать!

Comment: 1. нужен пример исходных данных. 2. нужно, чтобы другие поняли, что вы хотите сделать в конечном итоге. 3. iterrows - Чуть ли не худшее, что можно сделать с датафреймом.

Comment: Очень странно, по умолчанию индекс должен был сделаться стандартный от 0 и дальше. И покажите код, как вы пытались выставить индекс, когда у вас это не сработало. Индекс можно всегда сбросить через `reset_index()`, но надо не забывать про параметры. Вы результат `set_index` присваиваете обратно в `report_df` или делаете с параметром `inplace=True`?

Comment: Репутация меньше 15 - сайт не даёт проголосовать :( Но как решение отметил! :)

Comment: А зачем делать reset_index после вставки каждой строки?? Это надо сделать один раз в самом конце. Но, повторюсь, гораздо эффективнее накопить все данные в отдельные списки и создать DataFrame одним махом в конце, как показано у меня в ответе

Comment: Я понимаю, но в алгоритме необходимо иногда менять значения некоторых ячеек в зависимости от появляющихся результатов, а для этого нужно находить строки согласно условиям.. В DataFrame это понятно как сделать.. А если формировать массив списков, то там могут быть заморочки с поиском как мне кажется..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы используете очень неэффективные подходы:

1. `data_sience_csv.iterrows()` - один из самых медленных и неэффективных способов работы с DataFrame
2. Тоже самое можно сказать о добавлении по одной строке к DataFrame

**По первому пункту:**

Если вы поясните откуда и как вы получаете значения `s_compact`, `s_stat`, `iPointData`, то, наверняка, получите адекватный и идиоматический ответ.

Кроме того в вопросе [следует приводить небольшие воспроизводимые примеры входных данных и то, что вы зотите получить в результате](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

**По второму пункту:**

В общем случае, можно собрать списки значений для каждого столбца и в конце создать DataFrame  следующим образом:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": pd.to_datetime(list_of_date_strings),
    "Result": list_of_result_values,
    "Status": list_of_stats,
    "Count": pd.to_numeric(list_of_counts, errors="coerce")
})
```

Значения индекса тогда по умолчанию будут от 0 до N-1

Но, возможно, объяснив подробнее вашу задачу и приведя примеры входных и выходных данных, вам дадут более эффективный ответ.

---

**UPD:** чтобы установить индекс в DataFrame'е в виде целых чисел от `0` до `N-1`:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

PS эту операцию нужно делать  *после окончания заполнения DF*! Делать это на пустом DataFrame - бессмысленно, т.к. в пустом DF нет ни строк ни значений индекса.

Comment: Такой вариант заполнения не подходит.. Мне нужно именно создать пустой фрейм в начале, а потом его заполнять данными.

Comment: @ax.rogov2018, у вас наблюдается эффект туннельного зрения - вы сфокусировались на одном из возможных решений и не слышите подсказок) Советую ознакомиться: [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy)

Comment: Спасибо! Но я кажется писал: "Как указать индекс? Чтобы в первом столбце (который без имени) шли 0, 1, 2, 3 ... Т.е у DataFrame был числовой индекс, начинающийся с нуля." Кажется вы сейчас переписали тоже самое ) Да, и я это опробовал и повторил пробу ещё раз только что - всё равно индекс 0 0 0 0 ... и так до конца.. ((

Comment: @ax.rogov2018, не верю! (с) Станиславский. Можете выгрузить ваш DataFrame в CSV файл `df.to_csv(r"/path/to/df.csv", index=True)` или еще лучше в виде Pickle файла: `df.to_pickle(r"/path/to/df.pkl")` и выложить этот файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник, чтобы мы смогли воспроизвести вашу проблему?

Comment: Сделаю! Как выгружать - в курсе :)))) report_df.to_csv(csv_path2reports, sep=';')

Comment: @ax.rogov2018, проверьте обновленный ответ ;)

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, пользователь хочет, чтобы у создаваемого им DataFrame был индекс.
У самого была некоторое время назад такая же проблема, но решить не удалось и я забил на неё.
Судя по приведённому результату в DataFrame не получается установить индекс почему-то.
Я так понимаю, что автор хочет получить в 1 столбце индекс и чтобы была возможность сделать индекс в двух вариантах:

1. Числовой - когда нумерация идёт с нуля: т.е 1 строка - 0, 2-ая - 1, 3-я -2 и т.д.
2. Индекс по столбцу "Date".

P.S: ответ предыдущего автора не понятен

1. Какая разница какие входные данные.. Из приведённого примера видно, что они формируются в программе, потом передаются в функцию BuildReportItem, которая возвращает dict, добавляемый в DataFrame
2. И чем плох iterrows() если нужно перебрать все строки по одной?

Comment: В 99% случаев в Pandas можно обойтись без медленного итерирования по строкам, используя векторизированный подход. А для того, чтобы предложить правильное идиоматическое решение нужно понимать как выглядят входные и данные и что нужно из них получить в результате!

Comment: Да ну в 100% случаев медленный `iterrows` не нужен )